# Powershell to PHP script

Tags: php, powershell, web

I'm on a PowerShell script which return me information from distant servers
I want to enter this information in a database by passing it to PHP

PowerShell:

```
$postParams = @{ "site" = $localname; "comp" = $retrunvalue }
$req = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http://server_adress.com/index.php") 
-Method POST -Body $postParams
```

and on PHP:

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['site']) and isset($_POST['comp']))
    {
        echo 'Thanks';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'non reachable values';
    }
?>
```

But when I go to the website page I have an error saying that non reachable values (my code)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to echo the values of $_POST['site'] and $_POST['comp'] in the else part of your code. Clearly, your conditions aren't evaluating to true, so its probably not getting the values passed in the POST query.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_REQUEST)` give you?

Comment: Do you need to use PHP? Powershell leverages .Net and is able to connect into about every database.

Comment: Thanks, i did the test putting echo in the else and it says that $_POST['site'] is not in the index like there's no values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello everyBody i found finally something very powerfull ! with Powershell v3 we could use directly POST method !!
$URL = "http://example.com/foo/bar.php"

$postparam = @{TESTID= "524"; sitename = $localname; comp = 4; stream = "foo" }

```
    $webrequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Body $postparam -Method Post
```

Thanks i hope this will help someone !